# Conditional return type on TypeScript with boolean check doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, typescript

Given the following code:

```
type OpenFileDialogReturn<TMulti extends boolean> =
  TMulti extends true ? FileList | null | undefined :
  TMulti extends false ? File | null | undefined :
  never

type OpenFileDialog = {
  (options: { multiple?: false, acceptedFileTypes?: string }): Promise<OpenFileDialogReturn<false>>
  (options: { multiple: true, acceptedFileTypes?: string }): Promise<OpenFileDialogReturn<true>>
}

export const openFileDialog: OpenFileDialog = (options = { }) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const input = document.createElement('input')
    input.type = 'file'
    input.style.opacity = '0'

    if (options.acceptedFileTypes) input.accept = options.acceptedFileTypes
    if (options.multiple) input.multiple = true

    input.addEventListener('input', () => {
      if (options && options.multiple === true) resolve(input.files)

      const file = input.files?.[0]
      if (!file) resolve(null)

      resolve(file)
    })

    input.click()
  })
}
```

TypeScript is throwing an error on the last `resolve(file)`

```
Argument of type 'File | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FileList | PromiseLike<FileList | null | undefined> | null | undefined'.
  Type 'File' is not assignable to type 'FileList | PromiseLike<FileList | null | undefined> | null | undefined'.ts(2345)
const file: File | undefined
```

I've tried several approaches, even wrapping everything in strict if/else blocks to make sure that TS understands that `options.multiple` is strict `false` at this point but nothing seems to work. Any help is appreciated.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-2LN2rqCq8l3yq36JLY0AbTjAF1H8g64AIR3heixXrUcSoA+A4DpeqDZLUoHuts-YDsG4yoMg4wANaLr4qEbEAA)

Comment: `resolve(file)` is executed even if `if (file)` is `true`. You need an `else` statement. But the actual problem seems to be that `resolve` doesn't seem to expect to receive a `File`.

Comment: Hey @FelixKling `resolve(file)` being executed when file is not undefined is intended, and the type correctly seems to be typed to `File`, but it still complaints that its not a `FileList` which is odd since it _knows_ that `options.multiple` is false at this point

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for the answer, this is exactly what I was looking for. Mainly the fact that the promise internally was taking the first type, makes total sense. You want to copy your answer to an actual answer so I can mark it?

Comment: @Mosti - Done. I think there's a nuance around the `Promise` thing I'm not understanding, but that seems to be how it's happening in your code. (I haven't yet been able to prove it to myself separately, though.)

Comment: *"resolve(file) being executed when file is not undefined is intended"* Sorry, I meant that `resolve(file)` is executed even if `if(!file) resolve(null)` is executed. Calling `resolve` multiple times doesn't have any effect. Besides, if the promise can resolve to `null` and `undefined` anyway, why so you even have the `if (!file) resolve(null)` statements?

Comment: @FelixKling `resolve` terminates function execution like `return`, so it would never be executed

Comment: *"`resolve` terminates function execution"* [No it doesn't](https://jsfiddle.net/tckw0yrd/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're not providing a type argument on the `Promise` you're creating inside the function, TypeScript seems to be picking one of your overloads (the `FileList | null | undefined` one) and so it's rejecting the `resolve` using `File`. (I'm not sure of the details around the resolution there, but it [seems to relate to the order of the overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgQwLZgDYQGIFcB2BjYASwHscBBKAXigG8AoKRqACgDNUEBzALimACcsEAJS8ACv2JJCAZwgAeGQMI5OUAD5QcWVKgB8AbgZM2HHlFYJUc0VAlTZCgEbFi6BDg1ad+owF8jOlBIWEQUdGx8IlIAISpaY0ZTLl5LaxFxSWk5eRc3CA8vbV1DRJZ2FL5BDLssx0VlVSKfUoC6OgB6DqgAdUJgAAtQ5DRMXAIScgAaKH6oMH4IVgh+GSgAAzz3T01i1HWoYgA3FY2lfhU1XZ91ujxSJSgEAEZeeBGI8ejyeOTOYSoegSTCgi2AWH4nhwEAA7rUHHJmMxFjI3CcAZQgfQQSDCKwWABZBCDAB0-A8ABMpMwAfIoAAGEkAVgB2Jx7LxLAAhBV-sD2QLGCi0RA2FYbEZBSC-FAIOl+VKccLUCdmAAiOBq4SSxVQPxlaUGpjK1V7bVlPzmtp3B7AJ4AJjeYVGkQmpAo1D+GKxZTBEKhsPh2VFyIgqJVIkBCpxnOYRNJ5JwVKQNKgdMZLOjgtjvNZRsVJtFGq1OsVMrlcizusLYvS5t1evzjcFNbNpb1VsCXSgMSwdph-SG73CYyikxiMzmCyWKzW63Ol2augOx1Om1c2yX+xtOEeTlewxHru+cU9uajbKFEHBkK0gfswaRhe9VcYsfjAzJlOptIZzLzDaxjyZgAQ2xphiKtYSk20qyvKl5gTWxb1rq+qCmhAqtj4KGMJa-iBPcu52k4jqHi6Xzjr856YtGfq3tCcIPo4T4QRGL4Ibi+JxsSn6Jsmqbpv+r4xlx54cdWrGqsh7boXBlbiQWkmimk0ENhh7LqUqSnMG2FqdnQQA); I wouldn't rely on that.) And then as a result of its return type, the implementation function isn't compatible with the `OpenFileDialog` type.

Better TypeScript heads than mine have told me that it's not unusual for the implementation of an overloaded function to be not strictly compatible with all of its overload signatures — that is, for the implementation to be not perfectly typesafe. That being the case, you could type the promise as `File | FileList | null | undefined` so that at least the code within the promise executor is constrained to returning one of those things (even though, technically, a coding error could have it return a `FileList` when it should return a `File`), but then use a type assertion on the result (`as Promise<any>`, ugh) to make the implementation assignable to `OpenFileDialog`. (Or you could just use any as the type argument at the outset, but then the code in the executor is completely unconstrained.)

There's also a minor unrelated change you need to make: Mark `options` optional in the `false` signature in `OpenFileDialog`, since your implementation provides a default for it.

Something like this:

```typescript
type OpenFileDialogReturn<TMulti extends boolean> =
  TMulti extends true ? FileList | null | undefined :
  TMulti extends false ? File | null | undefined :
  never

type OpenFileDialog = {
  (options?: { multiple?: false, acceptedFileTypes?: string }): Promise<OpenFileDialogReturn<false>>
//        ^−−−−−−−−−−− make `options` optional in this signature
  (options: { multiple: true, acceptedFileTypes?: string }): Promise<OpenFileDialogReturn<true>>
}

export const openFileDialog: OpenFileDialog = (options = { }) => {
  return new Promise<File | FileList | null | undefined>(resolve => {
//                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    const input = document.createElement('input')
    input.type = 'file'
    input.style.opacity = '0'

    if (options.acceptedFileTypes) input.accept = options.acceptedFileTypes
    if (options.multiple) input.multiple = true

    input.addEventListener('input', () => {
      if (options && options.multiple === true) resolve(input.files)

      const file = input.files?.[0]
      if (!file) resolve(null)

      resolve(file)
    })

    input.click()
  }) as Promise<any>;
//   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^−−−−− to make the implementation compatible with the overloads (ugh)
}
```

Checking usage:

```typescript
const x = await openFileDialog({multiple: true});
//    ^? −−− const x: FileList | null | undefined
const y = await openFileDialog();
//    ^? −−− const y: File | null | undefined
const z = await openFileDialog({multiple: false});
//    ^? −−− const z: File | null | undefined
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8pB2AxAlgGwgEWQQ1QewHMAlCYAVwCd4AeAFQFkzVhkoIAPYCeAEwGcoAIzx502eAD4oAXgBQUKAyYs2nbvyjAKZaAH4oKdABlkfYFAA+UeE1SWoZXhABmyeBB5QAXPMWNmrBxcvALOuHx6BmjQVjaodlaOPC5uHt6+7gBuEBSysqCQsAiGmDj4BDJQAN6+ABR4YCx48Hy6XtVQALbKyGDobVBhqBEANFDYAMYTEI0eJbTgEK3tZhRuFQC+AJTtAAoUeJ2mENRw3CVYuIQk5FTUQxESEnUNTS3tVV09fRDtWjpjSbTWY8eaLZZQVbrKDbPYHI4RU7FaKXco3Sg0f4QJ6yDZ5DhgPAUcwTZpmKANc4osqEdpnJDUq4VaRQeqNZBkyqfbYyKQ1BQUUgY6wQADuUH2h2O1BK9hKJnJsVs9iSKXcPAktUFfFE2V51V8ClJLXMbjAZHMLJ4eAmZE63GAADoJoLsFwAKLoe3wYC1ADkZotfq2hqggadBWgLL9rnQftD4cdZhA6EdDUmyFAlT9AAZ4wnnKzXhyWo6gTMuKDogtIHwtmH4OaneXGpVi2Sy1MK3Nq+CC0X2R3ugEfvXE8OWD9Kli8goFInsDweO7sj6FcEcv7w36xrV69I+aH54W2W8BAAyc8Uwelie9dAyaQsrH17W6iC1ROxpYho9QY3kt+lRftErSOgA2jmAC6f7ICeACE36vks761HEqC-nOc5vqg2S1EhobbLOc6JhMqDIBMADWe6+Dy2ACJKCInOIIASAA3LieQAeY7CVNgorYJm15UugqKELUVR3j8fzaBA2wcQA9ApWEAHq6LI3FQCAfECUJlIMqJNIEHuinKXOakaWS5gAF46YJ5j6RcRkSVJ6DtA8clbKZqnqUAA)